# Drop duplicates and keep first in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

not familiar with R sorry for the question that I could not find already.

Suppose I have a network of IPs of data of this type:

`toy_data = data.table(from=c("A","B","A","C","D","C"), to=c("B","A","C","B","A","A"))`

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| A | C |
| C | B |
| D | A |
| C | A |

I cannot load the whole network in igraph and trying to compute statistics based on chunks. So given that the network is undirected I would like to drop all those lines that have the opposite from-to pattern (row 2, row 6).

I originally thought that something like this would work:
`unique(toy_data[,.(c(from,to)|c(to,from))])` unfortunately

I thought to use two auxiliary columns:

```
toy_data[,orig:=paste(from,to,sep="")]
toy_data[,reverse:=paste(to,from,sep="")]
```

then work with something like:
`unique(df[,.(?)])`

but my guess is that this is way easier than what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating temporary column, `paste` the min by row (`pmin`) with the `max` by row (`pmax`) and remove the duplicates with `duplicated` and negate (`!`)

```
toy_data[!duplicated(paste(pmin(from, to), pmax(from, to)))]
```

-output

```
    from     to
   <char> <char>
1:      A      B
2:      A      C
3:      C      B
4:      D      A
```